# Visual Studio. Adding numbers to end result

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a project where there are 3 buttons. Add, subtract and exit. When I click the "Add button it should take whatever is in the current "number ordered" box and add it to the total. If I click subtract it should subract from the current total. The buttons work but I can't get the total to stay. If I put in 5, click add, then the total box states 5 but the minute I erase it, the total box erases too. Here is my code:

```vb
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Option Infer Off

Public Class frmMain
    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(Sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        Dim intNumOrdered As Integer
        Dim dblTotal As Double


        Integer.TryParse(txtNumOrdered.Text, intNumOrdered)

        dblTotal = intNumOrdered + dblTotal

        lblTotal.Text = dblTotal.ToString("C2")


    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSubtract_Click(Sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubtract.Click
        Dim intNumOrdered As Integer
        Dim dblTotal As Double

        Integer.TryParse(txtNumOrdered.Text, intNumOrdered)

        dblTotal = dblTotal - intNumOrdered
        lblTotal.Text = dblTotal.ToString("C2")


    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
    Private Sub txtNumOrdered_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtNumOrdered.Enter
        txtNumOrdered.SelectAll()
    End Sub
    Private Sub txtNumOrdered_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtNumOrdered.TextChanged
        lblTotal.Text = String.Empty
    End Sub
End Class
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: `Dim dblTotal As Double` You never initialize `dblTotal` to anything. Should that be a class member instead of a local?

Comment: Or read it from the label each time: `Double.TryParse(lblTotal.Text, dblTotal)`

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> but the minute I erase [the contents of the numordered box], the total box erases too

And your code says:

```
Private Sub txtNumOrdered_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtNumOrdered.TextChanged
    lblTotal.Text = String.Empty
End Sub
```

To be fair, VB's only doing exactly what you've told it to do! :)

Comment: Thank you so much. Sorry am still working on learning things.

Comment: No need to apologize, sometimes these things are really hard to see..

Answer (score 0):

There is a few things wrong here. As pointed out already you are clearing the total box. Also you are not storing the total anywhere and instead using local variables which will initialize to 0. Another thing you should check your TryParse actually succeeds before using the variable.

```
Public Class frmMain
Private dblTotal As Integer = 0

Private Sub btnAdd_Click(Sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    Dim intNumOrdered As Integer

    If Integer.TryParse(txtNumOrdered.Text, intNumOrdered) Then
        dblTotal = dblTotal + intNumOrdered
        lblTotal.Text = dblTotal.ToString("C2")
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub btnSubtract_Click(Sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubtract.Click
    Dim intNumOrdered As Integer

    If Integer.TryParse(txtNumOrdered.Text, intNumOrdered) Then
        dblTotal = dblTotal - intNumOrdered
        lblTotal.Text = dblTotal.ToString("C2")
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
Private Sub txtNumOrdered_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtNumOrdered.Enter
    txtNumOrdered.SelectAll()
End Sub
Private Sub txtNumOrdered_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtNumOrdered.TextChanged
    lblTotal.Text = String.Empty
End Sub
```

End Class